# Correct specification of linear mixed model with repeated measures in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have a dataset with repeated measures data but I'm unsure of the specification of my model and subsequent contrasts:

In the dataset, participants responded to a measure (`Score`; continuous) at three different timepoints (`Time`; T1/T2/T3) that were not equally spaced (not sure if this is relevant). I'm informed that `Sex` and `Age` (older/younger) may have an impact on the outcome, so should be included in the model. However, due to a relatively small sample size, and some subgroups/cells potentially being empty, I don't think it would make sense to look at complex interactions between these variables (e.g., `Time*Sex*Age`) , but I would like to look at `Time*Sex` and `Time*Age`. So I think the following are fixed effects: `Time`, `Sex`, and `Age`, and `ID` would be a random effect and random slope.

So for issue 1: Could someone help me with the correct `lme4` syntax? My initial guess is: `mod <- lmer(Score ~ Time + Sex + Age + (1|ID), data=data)`. But I suspect this may be wrong because it doesn't include interactions and I'm not sure about the random aspects.

Then for issue 2: I'm hoping to use planned comparisons to look at differences in scores between T1 and T2. Then to answer a different question, I want to look at scores between T2 and T3, and T1 and T3.

I think the `emmeans` package could help with this, but I'm wondering about how to involve `Sex` and `Age` in the comparisons, if at all. I don't have specific hypotheses that involve these factors, but if they are presumed to have an impact on scores then it makes sense to include them somehow. Would this mean intending to run planned comparisons without them, but if either or both are found to be important in the lmer model, running some kind of post-hoc tests that feature these instead?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would make sure that you have `Time` as a factor (not just a quantitative variable) in your model.

Second, I would suggest nailing down the issue of "potentially empty cells". Am I correct that you *do* at least have every subject measured at all 3 times? Or are there holes there? I'm hoping not, but if there are, that may not be a disaster.

I suggest doing something like `with(data, table(Sex, Age))` to see if there are missing combinations of `Sex` and `Age`. If so, you really can't do a sensible analysis of either factor in its own right, and you might as well combine them into one factor, say `data <- transform(data, Group = interaction(Sex, Age))`

Then I'd suggest fitting the model including all interactions, because you don't know which to reasonably omit. So that'd be `Sex*Age*Time + (1|ID)` or `Group*Time + (1|ID)` depending on the previous paragraph. It does seem that if each subject is measured at the three times, then `(1|ID)` is a reasonable thing to put in for the error term.

For *post hoc* analysis, I don't see much validity to trying to pursue a small number of planned comparisons, because it all seems pretty exploratory at this point. Maybe save that for the next study that is more carefully designed and powered, and includes subjects in all age and sex combinations. By the time you finish mentioning what times you want to compare, you have covered all pairwise comparisons. So I suggest something like:

```
EMM <- emmeans(mod, ~ Sex * Age * Time)  ## or ~ Group * Time
pairs(EMM, simple = "Time")
```

The second statement will do all three pairwise comparisons of `Time` for each combination of the other factors.

It may be possible to do simpler comparisons if an anova (e.g., `car::Anova(mod)`) suggests that `Age` or `Sex` does not interact with `Time`. If so, you can fit a simpler model that excludes those interactions, and exclude that factor in `EMM` and we will just average over the levels of that factor.

Comment: `@Russ Lenth` many thanks for the insights. By empty cells, I meant there might only be a few or no responses for certain subgroups at a certain timepoint, like only one or two older males at T3. So I thought it might be better to avoid a `Sex*Time` interaction.

Comment: This makes me wonder about the procedure. I had the idea that you observe most or all subjects at 3 different times -- is that not correct? Why would there be empty cells at time 3? Do some subjects drop out early, or what? And you mention *including* `Sex*Time` in the OP, you were thinking of excluding `Sex*Age`. So what gives?

Comment: Most subjects were observed at all timepoints, but if I recall there was some attrition and with a relatively modest sample size to begin with, this meant that the number of a certain subgroup like older males fell to a very small number. So the `Sex*Time` was just intended to keep the group size healthier, like looking at how males vs. females got on over time, as opposed to older males vs younger males vs older females vs younger females over time.

Comment: I think I'd suggest carrying on along the lines I already outlined. BTW in the OP you mention random slopes. But I'd stick with the random-intercepts model. You already have pretty sparse data as I understand it, and I'd avoid getting too fancy with it.

Comment: Thanks Russ, that makes sense and I'm able to run both model and pairwise comparisons. One thing I'm still wondering about though, is that if the literature indicates that Sex may determine how scores change over time, and also indicates that Age may do the same, but there is nothing to suggest an interaction such that older males may perform differently to older females, should an interaction term still be included? From an exploratory perspective, I'm thinking perhaps it should.

Comment: And if the dataset was less sparse, would an appropriate model that allows for random slopes be `Sex*Age*Time + (1+Time|ID)`?

Comment: Yes, I think it is worth testing that interaction and re-fit if it isn't needed. That would be the way to specify random time effects, but you'd need to justify that that model is better than random intercepts.

Comment: Thanks Russ, this has been really helpful.